# ruby object id increment in steps of 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, pg

I have a ruby application using devise to handle user authentication an pg as my data store. I just noticed that the first user object_id is 2 and subsequent object id's increment in steps of 2.

I have dropped and recreated my local db several times and the issue still persists.

Has any one come across this before ?

Comment: Are you facing this at time of user creation?

Comment: Yes I am, Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to check your logs. Present them here if you still don't see reasons for duplicate object creation/sequence step.